# Can I debug modules in node-webkit loaded via require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-webkit

node-webkit seems to support debugging in a very convenient way, as you can easily open the devtools by clicking on the toolbar.

Using that approach I can easily debug any JavaScript that is inside my HTML page, and even though I have not tested it, I assume I can also debug other scripts loaded via the traditional browser way, i.e.

```
<script src="blabla.js"></script>
```

However this being node-webkit, I want to exploit the module approach of node, so I can develop clean independent modules and load them via require directly from my index.html, e.g.:

```
<script>
    var myFunc = require("./myfunc");
    myFunc();
</script>
```

This works perfectly fine. The problem is, I can't find a way to debug the content of myfunc.js. I can open the module file in the debugger and set a breakpoint there, but it won't stop at it. I have also tried to add a `debugger;` statement in my module, but that also does not work. I have also tried the remote debugger via `--remote-debugging-port=port`, with the same results.

Do you know whether debugging modules is supported by node-webkit? If so, how? Otherwise, is there some useful workaround that I can use while still being able to make use of modules?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that this is explicitly not supported. According to node-webkit wiki, https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Debugging-with-devtools#bugs-of-developer-tools:

> Node modules don't show in script sources

So I will have to stick with some workaround. Suggestions are welcome...

Comment: Well, that was long ago, but if I remember correctly, I used plain old console.log ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯